# Best way to store game states of a 2048 board when using a gametree in python

Tags: python, algorithm, event-sourcing

I have a minimax like function that can predict if a move in 2048 is a good move or not and give it a score. The only thing it is missing however is a way of remember each of the states in the game.

For example if you shift a board up (the equivalent of pressing up on the keyboard) how would I eventually be able to go back to that game state when I need to go back in depth and shift the original state to the right? What's the best way of doing this?

The board itself is stored as a 2d array fyi.

Comment: We need more details...how are you storing everything?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to store it that's what I was asking but I'll be more specific in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each state transition for 2048 is entirely contained in two events:

1- the previous move
2- the location and value of the new tile

If you know the starting board (the first two tiles randomly generated), and the sequence of transitions, you can reconstruct the board state at any step of the game.

A data structure to store this start state, and the sequence of events could be as simple as a list of tuples.

In other words, the way to approach "going back in time", is more like "re-running the time forward until you reach the state you want to observe". It is called [event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) and, to some extent, this is what the Git graph does, what the crypro-currencies ledger does, and probably what accounting software will do in the future too.

here is a good video introducing [event sourcing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUDN40rdly8)

In your specific case, if what you really want to do is **undo** or **rollback** the last few moves, the [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) might be a better option:
An easy way here would be to store each consecutive state in a list/array, and retrieve the state at each step from the index of the state in the sequence; you could also easily limit the number of steps to keep to the last n moves if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There are 16 squares in the 2048 board, and each one contains a power of 2 from 2^1 through 2^11.  Rounding up, it takes 4 bits to store a number from 1 to 11, so it only takes 16*4 = 64 bits to store the game state as 16 numbers from 1 to 11.

64 bits is not a lot, so you might as well store every game state directly instead of using something more indirect and complicated.  You could encode it into a `bytes` 8 bytes long, a 16-character hex `string`, or a long integer.  A long integer (`long` in python 2 or `int` in python 3) will probably end up being the most compact and easiest to work with.

Comment: Right but I already have a way of storing a board, I just need ways to be able to revert the board back to that state. I just store it as one entire 2d array.

Comment: Yes, I've seen some pretty nifty hex representations on some of the AI that were written for the game. Good post @MattTimmermans,  +1

Comment: @JamesLatimer You need to store *something* that indicates which state you want to revert back to.  The easiest *something* to store is just the entire previous state.   Presumably you're concerned with how much memory this would take, but since it fits into 64 bits that 's not actually a big deal.